# How do I create an msdos .com program that takes a file as parameter

Tags: assembly, dos, 16-bit

How do I create a .com program that accepts a file as a parameter. The .com program is to be executed from the Command line interpreter. I'm planning to write the program in Assembly language. Here is how its supposed to work. Let's say the program is `DecToHex.com` At the command line (in MSDOS) the user enters

```
DecToHex.com afile.dec
```

The program then converts `afile.dec` into hexadecimal and creates another file named `afile.hex`

P.S: This is to be done in MSDOS assembly language

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, MSDOS stores the command line parameters starting from CS:0080h.

You should be able to verify that with `debug.exe dectohex.com infile outfile`
Then disassemble / dump memory from cs:0 and search for the string.

As Frank reminded, asciiz was unknown to MSDOS, which instead used apparently pascal-type string format. One has to parse the string byte per byte -- and I suppose the command line parameters will be there as is. Eg. consecutive spaces will not be truncated.

Comment: [80h] contains a byte of "length" first, then probably a space, then your filename. Not zero-terminated - you'll have to zero terminate it before using it as a filename to the "open file" function (I'd have to look up the number). Then use it to create a name for your output file - or is that another parameter? Open that file, too. (check for error after both opens) Read N bytes from the input file into a buffer, convert 'em - probably into another buffer. Write that buffer into your output file. Go back and read more. Until done. Exit cleanly. What part(s) are you having trouble with?

Comment: Thanks, I would have checked that if I had XP or older.